# Calculate the sum of the operation in a string

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, c-strings

Problem Statement

You are given a string S consisting only +(Addition),*(Multiplication). The next line will contain two positive values.

Now, Calculate the sum of every operations. See the explanation for more clarification.

Input Format

```
First line contains a string S, consisting only +(Addition),*(Multiplication) operator.
The second line will contain two positive integers a and b
```

Constraints

```
1 <= |S| <= 20, where |S| means the length of S.
1<= a, b <= 50
```

Output Format

```
Print the summation which were perform based on String S.
```

Sample Input 0

type here

+*
5 10

Sample Output 0

65

Explanation 0

```
when S[i] = '+',Then a+b = 5 + 10 = 15 and sum = 15
when S[i] = '*',Then a*b = 5 * 10 = 50 and sum = 15 + 50 = 65
```

Sample Input 1

+***+
2 1

Sample Output 1

12

Following is my attempted code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    char S[20];
    int a,b,i,sum=0;
    scanf("%s %d %d",S, &a,&b);

    for(i=0; i<=20; i++){
        if (S[i]= "+"){
            sum+=a+b;
        }
        else{
            sum+=a*b;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Please format your question properly. The input/output exampels are a mess.

Comment: `char S[20];` is one too small for a _string_ of _length_ 20.  Better as `char S[20 + 1]; ... scanf("%20s %d %d", S, &a, &b);`.

Comment: Tip: enable all warnings to quickly see problem with code like `S[i]= "+"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have typos like

```
    if (S[i]= "+"){
```

where there is used the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==` or using string literals like `"+"` instead of integer character constants. and incorrect expression in the for loop.

At least change the for loop the following way

```
for ( i = 0; S[i] != '\0'; ++i ){
    if ( S[i] == '+' ){
        sum += a + b;
    }
    else if ( S[i] == '*' ){
        sum += a * b;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the assignment you need to check entered values of `a` and `b` that they are in the range `[1, 50]`.  And the call of `scanf` should be written like

```
scanf( "%19s %d %d", S, &a, &b );.
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand how you should write the parameters, but looking at your code I saw a error:

```
if (S[i]= "+"){
```

here you want to compare the value of S with index i with the plus sign

1. for compare you need to use `==`
2. S[i] is a char, you need to use '+'

the dobles "+" are for char* and not char.

I hope I was helpful.